# Where is Tile Map to Printer Paper Option in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: printing, arcgis-pro, tiling

Where is the Tile Map to Printer Paper Option in the print interface of ArcGIS pro?

I need to print a 96x96 map in three 36x96 sheets. I included a picture of ArcMap 10.4 to show the tiling options I am looking for in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible in ArcGIS Pro or not. It seems like they removed the ESRI specific print dialog and it takes you straight to the standard system print dialog.

A possible workaround would be to export the layout to a PDF and use the various tiled printing options available in Acrobat or Reader.

> - Tile Large Pages  Tile only the pages that are larger than the paper.
> - Tile All Pages  Tile all the pages in the PDF file.

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html

I do hope that somebody comes through with a less hacky solution.

Comment: In early editions of ArcGIS Pro there was *no* print option, the Esri recommended process was to export to PDF and then print that PDF if required.  This may be by-design.